# React render new images on button click (new fetch call to retrieve images each time)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two .js files App, and Image. Essentially whenever the Find EPI button is clicked in App.js an Image component is created where a fetch call is made to retrieve a list of of image srcs so that I can display it.

The problem I am facing is that I will click the button with the right API parameters, and the image will display but when I try to click the button again with new parameters the images will first clear. I would have to press the button again for the new images to appear.

I know it has to do something with the way I am triggering the `displayImage` in App.js (`handleClick()`). How would I go about switching the images straight without having to click it twice (to clear the show the images again).

I haven't used React in a while, so sorry if this is something trivial and has already been answered.

--- App.js ---

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Image from './Image';

class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageDate: '',
      displayImage: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ imageDate: event.target.value });
  };

  handleClick() {
    const {displayImage} = this.state;
    this.setState({displayImage : !displayImage});
  }

render(){

  const isDisplayImage = this.state.displayImage;

  return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <div className="form-group mb-4">
          <p className="text-center text-white"> Choose a date for Earth Polychromatic Image </p>
            <div className="date input-group p-0 shadow-sm">
              <input
                type="date"
                value = {this.state.imageDate}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                className="form-control py-4 px-4"
                id="imageDate"/>
              <div className ="input-group-append"><span className="input-group-text px-4"><i className="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div>
            </div>
            <div className="text-center" id="findEPI">
              <button onClick={this.handleClick} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Find EPI</button>
            </div>
              {isDisplayImage ? <Image imageDate = {this.state.imageDate}/> : ''}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

--- Image.js ---

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Image.css';
class Image extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const dateSplit = props.imageDate.split('-');
    this.state = {
      imageDate: props.imageDate,
      year: dateSplit[0],
      month: dateSplit[1],
      days: dateSplit[2],
      enhancedepiAPI: "https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/enhanced/date/" + props.imageDate,
      retrieveImageAPI: "https://epic.gsfc.nasa.gov/archive/natural/" + dateSplit[0] +
       "/" + dateSplit[1] + "/" + dateSplit[2] + "/png/epic_1b_",
      epiDate : [],
      displayImages: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const fetchPromise = fetch(this.state.enhancedepiAPI);
    const epiDate = this.state.epiDate;
    const retrieveImageAPI = this.state.retrieveImageAPI;

    fetchPromise.then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(images => {
      epiDate.push(images.map(image => retrieveImageAPI + image.identifier + ".png"));
      console.log(epiDate);
      this.setState({displayImages : true});
    });
  }

  render(){

    const displayImages = this.state.displayImages;
    const images = this.state.epiDate[0];

    return (
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div className="carousel-inner">
    {displayImages && images.map(function(imageSrc) {
                return (
                  <div className="carousel-item active">
                    <img className="d-block w-100" src={ imageSrc }/>
                  </div>
                );
              })} </div></div>
    );
  }



}



export default Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any issues with the code that makes it so you have to click twice.

But I found a few things you can improve to make the code a bit cleaner if you want.

In App.js you're destructuring off  isDisplayImage from state, but not imageDate. You can change it to:

```
const { isDisplayImage, imageDate } = this.state;
```

The other thing is, you're binding both handleChange and handleClick in the constructor, if you use arrow functions instead you would get rid of the binding calls in constructor, which is why arrow functions exist.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
   this.setState({ imageDate: event.target.value });
};

handleClick = () => {
   const {displayImage} = this.state;
   this.setState({displayImage : !displayImage});
}
```

Sorry that I couldn't resolve your issue.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the tips will definitely make those changes.